# flattening part of a cone

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am a design student, and I have recently been 3d modeling an ornament for the heel of a shoe. I have a nice oval conical frustum, but unfortunately I am having a lot of trouble turning it into a flat sheet. Since I am going to laser cut the iron and then bend it into the shape I need, I need to know what the outline of my shape is if it were flattened onto a sheet.

The measurements are as follows: [The outside edges are 12.274 cm(the shortest distance between the bottom and top arc), the distance between the two midpoints of the arcs is 13.1 cm,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVAh.jpg) [the bottom arc is 5.501 cm, the top edge is 13.315 cm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLJHX.jpg), [the outside angle between the body going up and the ground is 81.03 degrees,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVAh.jpg) [the distance between the left and right edges on the bottom is 2.814 cm (the cross section), and the distance on the top is 7.902 cm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q8hF.jpg). [Here is the overall perspective.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BcAn.png)

Comment: Cone or conical frustum??

Comment: A diagram will be a great way to explain the structure you describe and than explain what you try to achieve - what is meant by flattening? Cutting part?

Comment: If I understand your explanation - you need to get the circles of the arcs and from there all the rest will be possible to do.